# How do you stretch an entry to fit screen in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know that you can do it with `label.pack(fill=x)`, but I need to use grid. I searched around and found `root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)`, but they just center the entry in the middle of the screen, and I need the size to change too. I am new to this so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

import pyperclip

root = Tk()

def listify(userString, brackets=True, quotes=True):

    outputList = []
    outputString = ''

    if brackets == True:
        outputList.append('[')

    if quotes == True:
        outputList.append("\"")
    userString = str(userString)
    lastCharacter = ""

    for character in userString:

        if character == " " or character == '   ':

            if lastCharacter == " " or lastCharacter == '   ':
                pass

            elif lastCharacter != " " or lastCharacter != '   ':

                if quotes == True:
                    outputList.append("\"")

                outputList.append(', ')

                if quotes == True:
                    outputList.append("\"")

        else:
            outputList.append(character)

        lastCharacter = character

    if quotes == True:
        outputList.append("\"")
    if brackets == True:
        outputList.append("]")

    outputString = outputString.join(outputList)
    return(outputString)

def mainListify():

    outputLabel.destroy()
    pyperclip.copy(listify(userText.get(),bracketsVar.get(),quotesVar.get()))
    newLabel = Label(root, text = listify(userText.get(),bracketsVar.get(),quotesVar.get()))
    newLabel.grid()


userText = StringVar()
quotesVar = BooleanVar()
bracketsVar = BooleanVar()

quotesVar.set(True)
bracketsVar.set(True)

userEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=userText)
quotes = Checkbutton(root, text='Quotes', onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=quotesVar)
brackets = Checkbutton(root, text='Brackets', onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=bracketsVar)
startButton = Button(root, text='Start', command=mainListify)
outputLabel = Label(root, text='Output Will Show Here')


userEntry.grid(columnspan=2)
quotes.grid(row=1)
brackets.grid(row=1,column=1)
outputLabel.grid(row=3,column=1)
startButton.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **`sticky`** parameter of `grid`, which defines *`how to expand the widget if the resulting cell is larger than the widget itself`*.

Here is an example (stripped your code):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

userText = StringVar()
quotesVar = BooleanVar()
bracketsVar = BooleanVar()

quotesVar.set(True)
bracketsVar.set(True)

userEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=userText)
quotes = Checkbutton(root, text='Quotes', onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=quotesVar)
brackets = Checkbutton(root, text='Brackets', onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=bracketsVar)
startButton = Button(root, text='Start')
outputLabel = Label(root, text='Output Will Show Here')

userEntry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
quotes.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=10)# padx for horizontal spacing
brackets.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=10)
outputLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
startButton.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Result :

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to make it so the the quotes and brackets buttons stay centered underneath the entry when it gets stretched? Right now it stays on the very left.

Comment: @NullAndVoid For that I need one thing from you. Can the "Output will show here" be centered?

Comment: Yes that would actually be better

Comment: @NullAndVoid Edited. See if it fits your need.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the help!